# OpenGL - trouble passing ALL data into shader at once

Tags: performance, opengl, go, glsl, shader

I'm trying to display textures on quads (2 triangles) using opengl 3.3

Drawing a texture on a quad works great; however when I have ONE textures (sprite atlas) but using 2 quads(objects) to display different parts of the atlas. When in draw loop, they end up switching back and fourth(one disappears than appears again, etc) at their individual translated locations.

The way I'm drawing this is not the standard DrawElements for each quad(or object) but I package all quads, uv, translations, etc send them up to the shader as one big chunk (as "in" variables): Vertex shader:

```
 #version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
in vec3 vertexColor;
in vec2 vertexUV;
in vec3 translation;
in vec4 rotation;
in vec3 scale;
// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec2 UV;
// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec3 fragmentColor;
// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;

...

void main(){


    mat4 Model = mat4(1.0);

    mat4 t = translationMatrix(translation);
    mat4 s = scaleMatrix(scale);
    mat4 r = rotationMatrix(vec3(rotation), rotation[3]);

    Model *= t * r * s;


    gl_Position = MVP * Model * vec4 (vertexPosition_modelspace,1); //* MVP;

    // The color of each vertex will be interpolated
    // to produce the color of each fragment
    fragmentColor = vertexColor;

    // UV of the vertex. No special space for this one.
    UV = vertexUV;

}
```

Is the vertex shader working as I think it would with a large chunk of data - that it draws each segment passed up as uniform individually because it does not seem like it?  Is my train of thought correct on this?

For completeness this is my fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec3 fragmentColor;

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec2 UV;

// Ouput data
out vec4 color;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;

void main()
{

    // Output color = color of the texture at the specified UV
    color = texture2D( myTextureSampler, UV ).rgba;

}
```

A request for more information was made so I will put how i bind this data up to the vertex shader.  The following code is just one I use for my translations. I have more for color, rotation, scale, uv, etc:

```
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tvbo)
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(data.Translations)*4, gl.Ptr(data.Translations), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)
tAttrib := uint32(gl.GetAttribLocation(program, gl.Str("translation\x00")))
gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(tAttrib)
gl.VertexAttribPointer(tAttrib, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, nil)
```

...

```
gl.DrawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, int32(len(elements)), gl.UNSIGNED_INT, nil)
```

Comment: _"they end up switching back and fourth(one disappears than appears again, etc) at their individual translated locations."_ Sounds like z-fighting. What are the coordinates of the quads? Make sure they are not the exact same distance away from the camera (or disable depth test).

Comment: I don't think you can draw 2 quads with different textures in one draw call, unless your fragment shader has some way of knowing which texture to apply to which quad.

Comment: Drawing the same texture, but I have uv coords for each one if they were different.  It is a sprite atlas

Comment: Depth testing is off... Also the objects are not on top of each other.

Comment: what do you mean you pass data as `(as uniform variables)` you can change uniforms only prior rendering the whole thing so you can not switch textures outside shader (as you draw all at once)...

Comment: Can you post your rendering method with the call of `glDrawElements/Arrays`? As Spektre mentioned, you can set uniform variables only once before doing the rendering call and then again and render again.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, I am passing them in as "in" variables to the vertex shader.  Packing all vertices in the scene, translation, scale, rotate, uv, color, etc into different "in" variables per draw for WHOLE scene each time. This is done because of better performance of drawing lots of objects (no draw call for each object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I needed more input on this matter, I linked this page to reddit and someone was able to help me with one response! Anyways the reddit link is here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/3gyvlt/opengl_passing_all_scene_data_into_shader_each/

The issue of seeing two individual textures/quads after passing all vertices as one data structure over to vertex shader was because my element indices were off.  I needed to determine the correct index of each set of vertices for my 2 triangle(quad) objects.  Simply had to do something like this:

```
        vertexInfo.Elements = append(vertexInfo.Elements, uint32(idx*4), uint32(idx*4+1), uint32(idx*4+2), uint32(idx*4), uint32(idx*4+2), uint32(idx*4+3))
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have just single `sampler2D`**

- which means you have just single texture at your disposal
- regardless on how many of them you bind.
- If you really need to pass the data as single block
- then you should add sampler per each texture you got
- not sure how many objects/textures you have
- but you are limited by gfx hw limit on texture units with this way of data passing
- also you need to add another value to your data telling which primitive use which texture unit
- and inside fragment then select the right texture sampler ...

You should add stuff like this:

```
// vertex
in int usedtexture;
out int txr;

void main()
 {
 txr=usedtexture;
 }

// fragment
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler0;
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler1;
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler2;
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler3;
in vec2 UV;
in int txr;
out vec4 color;
void main
 {
      if (txr==0) color = texture2D( myTextureSampler0, UV ).rgba;
 else if (txr==1) color = texture2D( myTextureSampler1, UV ).rgba;
 else if (txr==2) color = texture2D( myTextureSampler2, UV ).rgba;
 else if (txr==3) color = texture2D( myTextureSampler3, UV ).rgba;
 else color=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
 }
```

**This way of passing is not good for these reasons:**

- number of used textures is limited to HW texture units limit
- if your rendering would need additional textures like normal/shininess/light maps
- then you need more then 1 texture per object type and your limit is suddenly divided by 2,3,4...
- You need `if/switch` statements inside fragment which can slow things down considerably
- Yes you can do it brunch less but then you would need to access all textures all the time increasing heat stress on gfx without reason...

**This kind of passing is suitable for**

- all textures inside single image (as you mentioned texture atlas)
- which can be faster this way and reasonable for scenes with small number of object types (or materials) but large object count...

Comment: Sorry I edited my post to explain more of what i'm doing. So i'm passing one huge texture atlas and breaking it out into different uv coords per picture inside that atlas.

Comment: @efel in that case its OK... When I tried to compile your shader you got errors in vertex shader: `0(24) : error C1008: undefined variable "translationMatrix"
0(25) : error C1008: undefined variable "scaleMatrix"
0(26) : error C1008: undefined variable "rotationMatrix"` they should be also passed as uniforms. therefore it does not link and you are rendering with fixed function instead (unless you did not post the whole shader ...)

Comment: the vertex shader is not full as it would be a lot to type... I have helper method that handle matrices for T-R-S in the vertex shader.  I tried to ease the confusion with putting "..." to signify that parts of the code were missing